# Add square bracket only if one set of values

Tags: powershell

I'm using this scrip for Azure monitoring with Zabbix:https://b-blog.info/en/monitoring-azure-resources-with-zabbix.html

If only one SQL database in output:

```
{"data":{
  "{#SERVERNAME}": "mojsql",
  "{#ID}": "/subscriptions/11111-222222/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/mojsql/databases/mojabaza",
  "{#DATABASENAME}": "mojabaza",
  "{#RGNAME}": "rg"
}
}
```

If more than one database then output is:

```
{"data":[
  {
    "{#DATABASENAME}": "mojabaza",
    "{#SERVERNAME}": "mojsql",
    "{#RGNAME}": "rg",
    "{#ID}": "/subscriptions1111-22222/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/mojsql/databases/mojabaza"
  },
  {
    "{#DATABASENAME}": "mojabaza1",
    "{#SERVERNAME}": "mojsql",
    "{#RGNAME}": "rg",
    "{#ID}": "/subscriptions/11111-22222/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/mojsql/databases/mojabaza1"
  }
]
}
```

Note square brackets are added automatically.

The issue is if only one database in resource group then i must add square brackets in order to see database in zabbix

```
'{"data":' + '[' + $($result | ConvertTo-Json) + ']' + "`n}";
```

If more than one database then double square brackets are added and Zabbix shows error.

Is it possible to write a condition if one output then add square brackets something like

if $($results)=1 then

```
'{"data":' + '[' + $($result | ConvertTo-Json) + ']' + "`n}";
```

else

```
'{"data":' + $($result | ConvertTo-Json)  + "`n}";
```

Comment: `If ($result.length -eq 1){...} else {...}`

Comment: @LotPings, it works, thank You !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use case is exactly what the PowerShell's [*array subexpression operator*, `@()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators), was designed for:

```
'{"data":' + (ConvertTo-Json @($result))  + "`n}"
```

**Wrapping a command in `@(...)` *guarantees* that its output is an *array***.

In other words:

- If the output already *is* an array (collection), it is, loosely speaking, left alone (technically, a copy of the output array is typically created).
- If it isn't, it is *wrapped in a array*, as the that array's only element.

Additionally, **in order for `ConvertTo-Json` to see the array as such, you mustn't use the *pipeline* and instead pass it as an *argument***:

Because the pipeline *unwraps* (unrolls) arguments implicitly, the following two commands are *identical*:

```
$result | ...

@($result) | ....  # !! identical
```